task.run using method that gets called by c++ dll
i am puzzled as to why when even after adding Device_ImageAcquired to the event ImageAcquired i am unable to acquire the data from the api to later display it
virtual void image_acquired(
    int width,
    int height,
    const uint16_t* image) override {
    dotnet_callback(width, height, image, );}

using a wrapper i am able to use the native method in the c# code
class dotnet_device : public sdk::sdk_device {public:

 using image_acquired_callback = void(uint16_t, uint16_t, int, int, const uint16_t*, bool);
 dotnet_device(image_acquired_callback* dotnet_callback) : dotnet_callback(dotnet_callback) {}
private:

  image_acquired_callback* dotnet_callback; 
protected:

virtual void image_acquired(
    int width,
    int height,
    const uint16_t* image) override {
    dotnet_callback(width, height, image);

}};

and then on the c# side
[UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    unsafe public delegate void ImageAcquiredCallback(int width, int height, ushort* image,);

then i create the methods
unsafe public  class SdkDevice : IDisposable


{//other things
public event ImageAcquiredCallback ImageAcquired;
private unsafe void OnImageAcquired(ushort bank, ushort frame, int width, int height, ushort* image, bool moreAvailable)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("ciao"); Task.Run(() => ImageAcquired?.Invoke(width, height, image));}}

// i have since then taken out this messagebox line, keeping becayse of a reply
i then proceed to acquire the images using the dll
var device = new NativeMethods.SdkDevice();
        device.connect();
        device.StartAcquisition();

        device.ImageAcquired += Device_ImageAcquired;
        unsafe void Device_ImageAcquired(int width, int height, ushort* image)
        {// image processing with emgucv}


Are you sure OnImageAcquired get called?

@shingo it doesn't get called that's the issue. not sure what you mean. int the dll when i run it as a program in of itself image_acuired gets callled and i can save the image but OnImageAcquired doesn't

Since there is no place to call it, then the message box will certainly not appear.

so it could be that OnImageacquired is getting called but messagebox doesn't appear? how would i go about testing if it is called then? @shingo

That's what I want to ask at the beginning, so you are not sure. Do you have code that calls the method in your project? Have you tried to debug it?

that's all the code i have regarding the method at the moment. do i need to add code to use it? debugging it gave me no answer, simply doesn't show the image, the rest of the program works @shingo

Is there any update? How did you call the C++ DLL in C#?  Where is StnDevice.OnImageAcquired called?

@MinxinYu-MSFT i never had an issue calling the dll in c# i made a mistake in the code that didn't let the dll call image_acquired. it had to do with the library itself. i've got it to work now

Glad to know your problem has been solved! See Can I answer my own question?  Just a reminder :)

I may be missing something, but I fail to see how the native and c# code is connected. I would have expected either a bunch of p/Invoke code to register the callback with the library, or a C++/CLI project that exposes managed classes. But I do not see StnDevice.OnImageAcquired ever being used.
But there seem to be some other issues. Note that I have not seen your API documentation so some of this will be based on conjecture, and experience of how other native image capturing APIs work.
private unsafe void OnImageAcquired(ushort bank, ushort frame, int width, int height, ushort* image, bool moreAvailable)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("ciao"); // this doesn't appear
            Task.Run(() => ImageAcquired?.Invoke(bank, frame, width, height, image, moreAvailable));}}

This seem super dangerous, since it is capturing a pointer. I would assume that you only maintain ownership over the image pointer while the callback is running. As soon as OnImageAcquired returns the library can release or reuse the memory. This will obviously not work if the memory is used by another thread. To fix this you should probably copy the image data to managed memory before doing anything involving another thread. Or keep running whatever processing you are doing on the same thread.
I would also assume OnImageAcquired will be called from some background thread, so using UI methods like MessageBox.Show may not work like you expect. Writing something to a log file or placing a breakpoint are much better methods to see if you reach the method. Only do UI-things from the UI thread.
You might also want to consider some kind of pipeline or message queue system, like DataFlow, to allow frames to be processed concurrently, while still displaying the result in-order on the UI thread.

thank you for your reply, how would i go about copying the image data to managed memory? every time image_acquired is called in the c++ dll what do i need to do to the data?

@fish Create a byte array of sufficient size, use fixed to get a pointer to the byte array, and call Buffer.MemoryCopy to copy the actual data, You could also create a pool of buffers to reuse. The details will likely depend on exact use case.

for clarification, this wasn't the issue. there is no other thread using the image. Also messagebox does work in this case. thank you again and have a good day


the messagebox is there but doesn't appear when i use the methods in
the form with a button click in this case

You subscribed to the event, but did not call the method that triggered the event.
  device.ImageAcquired += Device_ImageAcquired;

// add method to call device.OnImageAcquired here

   unsafe void Device_ImageAcquired(ushort bank, ushort frame, int width, int height, ushort* image, bool moreAvailable)


the error is something that cannot be known without reading the documentation of this specific sdk, it is missing
set_parameters()

that's all
